# Find repetitive in list

Tags: linq, list, duplicates

I have an list of person same as below:

```
List<Person> Persons=New List<Person>
```

Person class contains some property such as Id,Firstname,LastName,Age,...
in this list exist some repetitive object with same Firstname and LastName

how can i recognize and find repetitive objects Id?

Comment: you mean firstname = lastname) or (firstname = firstname and lastname = lastnam)?

Comment: firstname = firstname and lastname = lastnam

Comment: Hope you got your answer from the links provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Eric White's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/19/find-duplicates-using-linq.aspx):

```
int[] listOfItems = new[] { 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 4, 3 };
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
foreach (var d in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Comment: I want to find exactly my repetitive object position in list! not group by result.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, this should create a unique list if this is what you're after:

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(list1));
```